# Multiple images import from folder outside of Nodejs/REACT project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm building an nodejs/react/webpack App (Portfolio) that display hundreds of images.
This webpack require.context works fine as long as I don't use variable for the image folder path (As the doc says, parameters needs to be literals)

```js
function importAllImages(r) {
  const images = {};
  r.keys().forEach(item => {
    images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item);
  });
  return images;
}

const allImages = importAllImages(
  require.context('./../../../../photoLibrary/painting', false, /\.jpe?g$/),
);
```

But the image files reside outside of the project, somewhere else on the server. The different paths for dev and prod are set into environment variable.
So is there any way to set up a context with image folder path that depends on environment variable ?
Or maybe I am not having a good approach, should I consider this problem in an other way ?
Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for my "french" english...